# Flutter stream does not update global variable

Tags: flutter

On my firebase server i have a document which contains a bool field with the value "true"

I created a stream to listen for this value:

```
final CollectionReference _ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
Stream? getValue;
bool value = false;//Global variable

void initState() {
super.initState();
getValue = _ref.doc().collection("list").doc().snapshots();
getValue.forEach((element){
 value = element["value"];
 print(value);//Shows the correct value if it changes
 });
```

}

//Somewhere else in the code but in the same class
print(value);//Shows always false even if i change it on firebase to true and i don`t know why?

Let meh know if you needmore information, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To update your value in a StatefulWidget, you should wrap with a setState.

```
_ref.doc().collection("list").doc().snapshots().listen((element) {
  if (!mounted) {
    return;
  }
  setState(() {
    value = element["value"];
  });
});
```

Comment: In a stream? If i setState in a streambuilder or ValueListenableBuilder i get an error

Comment: This should actually be happening in a listener, which I don't see in your code anywhere. I've updated my answer.